# Solution to Ax=b with Least Squares

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's suppose $A$ is a matrix such that $\ker A=\{0\}$ and $b$ is a vector not in the image of $A$.  This situation implies $Ax=b$ does not have a solution.

This is where least squares comes in.  Since $b$ is not in the image, we project $b$ onto the image of $A$ to get some vector $b'$ where then the equation $Ax=b'$ is solvable by $\hat{x}$.  This $\hat{x}$ is *not* the least-squares solution to $Ax=b$.

My question is, if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent and we project $b$ to get $b'\in image(A)$, then why can't we just row-reduce $Ax=b'$ to get the solution $\hat{x}?$  Instead, we must solve the normal equation $A^TAx=A^Tb.$  I get that $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ is a projection map, but I am looking for something more fundamental.

Comment: Is there some reason for not being satisfied with my answer? I am ready to explain.

Comment: There are other ways to solve than the normal equations, which are numerically ill-conditioned.

Answer (score 0):

Remember : Since you **estimating** a solution using LSQ, the more the data you account for, the better.

Example.

Suppose you have 3 variables.

Theoretically, you need only $3$ equations i.e. a $3\times 3 $ matrix is what you need.

However if you have **one** more equation from the data collected i.e. a $4\times 3$ matrix, theoritically the last equation should be a linear combination of the above $3$ . However practiacally, (quite obvious) things will differ.

So, now since the columns are independent, if you go by **row-reduction** , you will take account of only the **first** $3$ equations, i.e. the data from the $4th$ equation is not taken into account.

However , If you multiply by $A^t$, you get a square matrix, and it **will** be invertible (WHY?) .But now, you have accounted for the entire data!

So the latter ( by *Remember* ) will give a better approxiamtion than Row-reduction.

Comment: True, but this doesn't explicitly spell out why $x'$ is not the solution to $Ax=b'$ where $b'$ is the projection of $b$ onto the column space of $A$.  Since $b'$ has been particularly constructed (orthogonally chosen) to be in $Col (A),$ we know $Ax=b'$ has a solution.  Why is this solution not $\hat{x}?$

Comment: @NoClue Again you forget my **Remember**. This is statistics. You cannot modify **observed** data. $b$  is an observed data. Once you project it , you are biasing the observation.In fact you are using a **wrong** observation to find $x$ . Thats why, it is inaccurate

Comment: Then how does this explain why the following works:  Since the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, the Gram-Schmidt Process can be used to create the matrix $Q$ with column space equal to that of $A$ and $Q$ has orthonormal columns.  The projection $QQ^T$ applied to $b$ to get $\hat{b}$ then gives $Ax=\hat{b}$ the least squares solution. (I am approaching this from linear algebra rather than statistics.)  My projection should "bias" my data by your explanation.

Comment: @NoClue In the Gram-Schimdt process, we are **_NOT_** changing any observed data ! We are **just** writing $A$ in another form, and multiplying both sides by the Identity matrix. $I=QQ^t$. This gives us certain upper hands in **solving** the system of equations. It **doesnot** alter any data originally observed!

Comment: $QQ^T=I$ only when $Q$ is square... I see what you are saying regarding changing the data, etc., but I am asking *why* this is occurring.  To put it differently, it seems like a lot of hand-waving for why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could. The result would be the same. Solving the normal equations is just one method.

Comment: But it doesn't!  That's the entire problem:  Projecting $b$ onto Col $A$ to get $b'$ and solving $Ax=b'$ [via row reduction; solving by the inverse obviously doesn't apply] does not provide the least squares solution.

Comment: Do you have a small example where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The least-square approach is based on the minimization of the quadratic error,

$$E=\|Ax-b\|^2=(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b).$$

Differentiating on $x$, we cancel

$$\dfrac{dE}{dx}=2A^T(Ax-b)$$

so that

$$A^TAx=A^Tb.$$

The error minimization is achieved by an orthogonal projection.

Answer (score 0):

$\hat{x}$ *is* the least squares solution, though. The projection matrix is constructed as

$$P = A (A^TA)^{-1} A^T.$$

So,

$$b' = Pb = A (A^TA)^{-1} A^T b.$$

Which means

$$\hat{x} = (A^TA)^{-1} A^T b$$

is the solution to both $Ax = b'$ and the least squares problem. You can also show that $\hat{x}$ is unique since $A^TA$ is invertible.